# Deforming contours in the saddle point method

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently trying to understand the saddle point method using [this document](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/saddle.pdf) and in it the author makes the following statement:

> Thus for the problem at hand, we deform the contour until the maximum of $\mathrm{Re} \, g$ along the contour is also a stationary point of the phase $\mathrm{Im} \, g$.

where $g(z)$ is an analytic function appearing in the integrand of a certain contour integral alongside some other analytic functions. The nature of this integral is not so important to my question, which is the following.

If $g(z)$ is complex-differentiable and if $\mathrm{Re} \, g$ is stationary with respect to the contour parameter $t$ at certain point $z^\ast$ *along the contour*, then $g^\prime (z^\ast) = 0$ by Cauchy-Riemann. If $\mathrm{Re} \, g = u(x,y)$ and $\mathrm{Im} \, g = v(x,y)$ then at this stationary point $\partial u/\partial x = \partial u/\partial y = 0$. It then follows again by Cauchy-Riemann that $\partial v/\partial x = \partial v/\partial y = 0$, which implies that $v$ is also stationary along the contour. So it would seem that no deformation of the contour is necessary. The condition is automatically satisfied by the complex-differentiability of $g$. So why does the author imply that deformation is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have identified the issue. A stationary point of $u$ does not imply a stationary point of $g$, merely that the real part of $g^\prime$ is zero at that point.